# Running AsyncTask with button performClick

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a fragment that contains a Button `btn_connect` that when it is pressed a WiFi Direct connection is established between 2 devices. This fragment implements ConnectionInfoListener. So it has `onConnectionInfoAvailable` function where I want to execute an AsyncTask class. The problem that I have is that in one Activity, I am doing:

```
fragment.mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect).performClick();
```

And the button is being clicked and the connection is established so the code goes into the onConnectionInfoAvailable function but the AsyncTask is not being executed.

```
    @Override
    public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(final WifiP2pInfo info) {
        //..code..
        Log.d("Test 1", "Test 1");
        new MasterServerTask().execute();   
    }



public class MasterServerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            //**************
            Log.d("IM INSIDE ASYNCTASK CLASS", "SOCKET");
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8090);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        while (true) {//wait for clients
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("ACCEPTED A SLAVE DEVICE "+num_clients, "ACCEPTED A SLAVE DEVICE "+num_clients);
            num_clients++;

            OutputStream os=null;
            try {
                os = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            proxy.addSlaveOutputStream(os);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}



mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {//Phone that connects first is NOT the group owner
                //  port = Integer.parseInt(editTextPort.getText().toString());

                Log.d("IM IN THE OTHER FRAGMENT", "Connect");
                WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
                config.groupOwnerIntent = 0;
                config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
                config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
                if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Press back to cancel",
                        "Connecting to :" + device.deviceAddress, true, true

                        );
                ((DeviceActionListener) getActivity()).connect(config);
            }
        });
```

Is there an easy workaround solution for this?

Comment: Can you show how your task is set up? Also how you know that it isn't being called. Is `Log.d("Test 1", "Test 1");` being called?

Comment: Lod.d("test 1", "test 1") is being called. I have another Log that is inside the doInBackground() that is not being called

Comment: There can be  something inside in AsyncTask went wrong .

Comment: So show the `AsyncTask`. Something might be set up wrong

Comment: The AsyncTask works well when I manually press the button.

Comment: Just a feedback item for you on the way this `AsyncTask` is structured: you should not have the `doInBackground` loop indefinitely.  The `AsyncTask` is intended to be a short lived background operation (several seconds at most.)  If you need a long term background thread for something like a network server you should use a true `Thread` that you manage (possibly within a `Service`.)  With this structured as it is, it will prevent *any* additional `AsyncTask` instances from executing.

Comment: maybe your `MasterServerTask` works, just `socket = serverSocket.accept ();` wait until the client is not connected, that is, he sleeps

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish The log in the MasterServerTask is not being printed

Comment: This ties in w/my last comment: are you trying to get this `onConnectionInfoAvailable()` to trigger the `AsyncTask` after you have pressed a button which has already triggered the task?  In other words, the same run of the app without a rebuild/restart.  If so, the "new" task from the callback will not run because the previous one is still in its while loop.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer Yes that is what I am trying to do. I am aware now that that's what is preventing it from being executed. Any easy solution that fix it?

Comment: @ZiadHalabi it really depends on what you intend to do. Definitely look at using either a Thread or even an IntentService.  Be careful with the IntentService, though, as you could run into a similar situation if you are not careful.

Comment: Can you show the code the performClick() executes? You say the AsyncTask works if you click the button manually, so there should be an OnClickListener or a method referenced by android:onclick. It would be interesting to see that method.

Comment: @Ridcully I edited the question. The button connects 2 devices via WiFi Direct. Note that the button is in the Fragment and not in the Activity where the performClick() is being called. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments on the question were really helpful. The reason why the AsyncTask was not getting executed is because it was called from another task that is currently being executed. So in order for it to work, I replaced the `AsyncTask` with `Thread` classes. All the code in the `doInBackground()` was placed inside the thread's `run()` function. Now the performClick() executes a Thread, not an AsyncTask and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check how/where you are calling `WifiP2pManager.initialize()` to create the `WifiP2pManager.Channel` object.  The `Looper` you provide it is the one which will receive all callbacks for your instance of `WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener`.  If you are giving it a background thread then the `AsyncTask` will not execute - it must be started from the main (UI) thread.

Comment: channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null); is done in the Activity's onCreate(). Thing is that the onConnectionInfoListener is being executed. And I tried to let the Activity implement onConnectionInfoListener but its onConnectionInfoListener function wasn't called.